# Submitting a form with html table, and dynamically allocating rows with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a post form with an embedded html table, and use javascript to allow this table to add and delete rows.

I have been having an issue with linking the new rows to the html variable arrays that should store the values if submitted.

Please Help!

Here is my javascript function,

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID); //access the table to dynamically allocate it. 

    var rowLen = table.rows.length; // Store number of rows
    var toAdd = table.insertRow(rowLen);

    var index = toAdd.insertCell(0);
    var element0 = document.createElement("input");
    element0.type = "checkbox";
    element0.name = "toDelete[rowLen]";
    index.appendChild(element0);


    var industry = toAdd.insertCell(1);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.name = "Industry[rowLen]";
    industry.appendChild(element1);

}
```

Where `toDelete` and `Industry` are the html table variable that stores the values of each new row added.

Here is important html:

```
<BODY>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <form  method="post" action="test.php">
        <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
            <tr> 
                <th></th>
                <th></th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="toDelete[]"</></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Industry[]"</></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

When I access the `$_POST` variable in "test.php", nothing is stored, and the count length for each variable is never more than 2, no matter the number of rows.

Comment: Your inputs seems to be incorrectly written. Try `<input type="checkbox" name="toDelete[]" />`. You have an extra `<` in both of your inputs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the exact result you want, but it seems that you're trying to interpolate the variables into the input name.

```
element0.name = "toDelete[rowLen]";
element1.name = "Industry[rowLen]";
```

To do that, you need to concatenate

```
element0.name = "toDelete[" + rowLen + "]";
element1.name = "Industry[" + rowLen + "]";
```